# Is it possible to detect the names and types of local variables declared in a function?

Tags: python, variables, types, global, local

it is possible to detect the number of local variables declared in python. Now is it possible to get their names and types also by the help of user defined coding?? What is it in case of global variables??

Comment: Use  the `locals()` function.

Answer (score 0):

to get a variable type you can do something like this for example:

```
num = 10

print(type(num))
```

Output:

```
<class 'int'>
```